# An issue installing VMware Tools on Linux Mint 13

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, linux-mint, vmware-tools

I have followed the installation procedures found here:

http://install-climber.blogspot.com/2012/08/linuxmint13cinnamoninstallvmwaretools.html

however, at the end when I execute the command "/usr/bin/vmware-user" I receive the following errors:

```
jay-virtual-machine vmware-tools-distrib # /usr/bin/vmware-user
jay-virtual-machine vmware-tools-distrib # /usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libstdc++.so.6/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1)
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so
jay-virtual-machine vmware-tools-distrib #
```

I am running on VMware Workstation 9.0.

I'm a Linux newbie so any kind of direction would serve me well.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: This should have been posted on Superuser.com

Comment: Well apparently looking online at other problems similar to yours: I recommend finding a "downgrader" to downgrade your glibc, because most of the solutions out there are either advanced configurations or not solutions at all.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Superuser.com. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

I really should have thought of this earlier. I use VMWare tools on linux, I use the package: "open-vm-tools" and it works very well. Find it in your synaptics package manager.

Or simply go to terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

Optional, extra vmware things:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-dkms
sudo apt-get install open-vm-toolbox
```

(I think dkms is for modules so you probably want to have it)

The other method would be to downgrade to the package version that the installation version wants, wait until they update the package, OR modify the package script itself. These things might require more work and I can't help you without access to a similar virtual machine setup.

Downgrading a package:

```
sudo apt-get install packagename=version
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for looking. I did find this example online but when doing a locate, there were no instances of the libstdc++.so.6 files in any of the vmware folders.

Comment: Sorry about that I'll keep searching, I think it might be possible to downgrade the package with dpkg. Sec I'll update my main post.